# What are these plaques in Voyager's briefing room?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the briefing room of USS Voyager, there is a strangely-shaped plaque or model on the wall, in the little alcove near the door:

[image]
<sub>(S05E17 - The Disease @ 34:38)</sub>

At some point in season 5 they moved it to the adjoining wall, and it began to be seen much more often:

[image]
<sub>(S05E26 - Equinox, Part 1 @ 36:53)</sub>

[image]
<sub>(S07E04 - Repression @ 15:29)</sub>

There is another thing on the wall on the other side of the room, which is even harder to see clearly:

[image]
<sub>(S06E03 - Barge Of The Dead @ 25:38)</sub>

[image]
<sub>(S07E04 - Repression @ 15:19)</sub>

I looked out for a close-up of these things while rewatching Voyager recently but I'm still not sure what they're supposed to be. Are they symbolic? Models of ships? Just set dressing?

Comment: Speaking of which; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Briefing_room_wall_decoration.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Ah ha! Seems they altered it at some point. I only became aware of the plaques about half-way through the series, so I missed that fact.

Comment: Modern art, I would say.

Comment: I'd guess those pieces are Vulcan, all circles and corners very IDIC. That or it's just some junk Neelix had on his ship.